# How do you send a Twilio SMS with a session already started?

Tags: php, session, sms, twilio

I am trying to track a twilio (twilio.com) conversation between text messages. I want the sent message to contain a session variable ($gameID), but I seem to only be able to set it on reply? I want to send the gameID in the text, so that if they reply "Yes", I'll know which gameID they were referring to.

Is it possible to set a session variable on send? Here is the process flow:

- Send an SMS to a recipient with a unique GameID
- Recipient replies with "Y" or "N" and the unique GameID is returned
- My system then takes that response, the GameID and the phone number, then updates my database with Y or N.

Comment: This needs more context and possibly some code

Comment: Thanks. I've added some more context. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

Sounds like you are using the REST API to send the first message.  If thats the case instead of using session, you could just remember the phone numbers that you have sent messages to, then when they reply look at the From number and match it up with the message you'd sent earlier.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Devin, this would help if there wasn't a chance of the user receiving two messages for two different games. It seems like this might be my only option though.

Comment: Hi @devin, I'm still struggling with this. Here is exactly what I'm trying to do: - Send an SMS to a recipient with a unique GameID
- Recipient replies with "Y" or "N" and the unique GameID is returned
- My system then takes that response, the GameID, and the phone number and updates my database with Y or N

Comment: @jon There is no way to add extra "metadata" directly to a text message, so the best option is for your app that is sending the text to remember what GameID it just sent to a specific phone number and then do caller ID detection when people send responses back to your Twilio phone number.  The cookie that Twilio sets only exists between Twilios servers and your Message URL, so it only gets created once we make a request to that URL.  The cookie is not actually part of the SMS sent to the carrier.

Comment: Thanks Devin. That's what I figured. I've done a work around and it seems to work nicely now. I've simply limited it to one text per user, until they respond. Once they respond, they're able to receive a new text message. Should work for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could have several Twilio phone numbers that you rotate between sessions. For example, If you have 10 numbers, you send first message from number 1. Then, if the client has a second game, use number 2. You can then allow every user to have 10 simultaneous games at a time. If you keep a session alive for more than one back-and-forth, There will have to be a session expiry.